# Not using functions for speed? (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, execution-time

I'm writing a program for a competition in my class. It already works great and now I'm trying to make it as fast as possible. My question is- would just pasting what a function returns, wherever I want to use it, speedup my program as compared to making a user defined function? I know that function calls causes a jump in memory, so does doing this measurably speedup my code?
I don't care about readability in this case

Eg. Instead of doing this

```
while(something){
y = function();
}
double function(){
return f(x);
}
```

I do this

```
while(something){
y = f(x);
}
```

I've already done stuff like passing structures by reference, avoiding casting, using shift operations, using things like ++i, etc. for a faster execution time, and I'm looking to gain a small edge.

Comment: **Try it**. Be careful to make meaningful measurements. In particular, turn on optimizations.

Comment: @MichaelB What optimization flags are you passing to your compiler?  If using `++i` instead of `i++` gives a measurable performance gain, it is likely you are speed testing a debug build.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so I'm not sure what you mean by a debug build. I'm using the code more like a 'script' to numerically solve some ODEs. I'm compiling with 'g++ main.cpp -o -Wall main'

Comment: @MichaelB add `-O3`

Comment: Your best chance to get meaningful speedup is by using cache friendly structures, e.g. `vector` over list, `unordered_map` over `map` etc. Inlining a function saves you just few instructions involving stack manipulation, that's beyond what you can reliably measure. `Cache miss` on the other hand will hurt you 10x more.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That actually dropped execution time by almost 30%. That's incredible. Is this the only downside to this a longer compile time?

Comment: yes, compiler optimization will effectively keep the code as-is (e.g. the compiler may reorder instructions as long as all reads will produce the same outcome) +++ if you want to get hands on what your compiler does for you, check [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) from Matt Godbolt, and maybe have a look on the youtube channel of [Jason Turner](https://www.youtube.com/user/lefticus1)

Comment: @MichaelB as long as you don't rely on undefined behavior anywhere in your code, `-O3` generally has no downsides.

Comment: Debug builds are intended to make it easier to find bugs.  They are default, because you first want your code correct.  Then you say "optimize" to make it faster.  The various levels do different things; some prefer code size, for example.  O3 is good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, none of that ought to matter.

Optimizing compilers are really, really good at determining when to perform *strength reduction* (turning multiplication into adds or shifts) or *inlining* (eliminating the overhead of the function call).

You should focus your time and effort, as a human, on writing concise, maintainable and readable code, with the right algorithmic complexity, and then rely on the compiler to do the right optimizations.

You may find in rare circumstances that manual inlining (what you're doing) will yield significant perf benefits, but you should let a profiler guide you to the places where doing that will be beneficial.  Not just doing it because you think it'll be faster, because it usually won't.

Also, you noted in a comment reply that you're not compiling with `-O3`.  That means you're getting *no* optimization help from the compiler.  Add `-O3`.

Comment: I've already spent time trying to determine the most efficient algorithm I could use for the problem. When I tried 'strength reduction' and using prefix operators I noticed an actual ~1.3x increase in speed. Under normal circumstances I would think doing it is ridiculous but considering that others way be using the same numericals methods as I am, kind of motivates me to do tiny things like this.

Comment: If you can confirm you've got optimizations already turned on as well, then great!

Comment: TIL optimization flags are a thing and the compiler doesn't do it for you automatically. Cool.

Comment: Yes - the reason it doesn't do it automatically is that (a) builds can take *much* longer, which is bad when you just want to iterate quickly, and (b) it reduces debugability, because sometimes variables or functions may appear to no longer exist, and other such oddness.